# Java error from distriqt Adverts extension

Tags: air, ane, distriqt

I'm trying to get the distriqt Adverts extension to work in my AIR app.
On every device that I try my app on, I get that `Adverts.service.interstitials.isSupported` returns `false`.
On one device, I also get these Java errors, which is probably the reason why:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled error:. text=Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.adobe.fre.FREObject.getAsString()' on a null object reference
Error #2044: Unhandled error:. text=Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean com.distriqt.extension.adverts.platforms.AdvertPlatform.isInterstitialsSupported()' on a null object reference
```

I checked and double checked that all required extension are listed in the `<extensions>` section in the application descriptor xml, and that they are actually included in the APK.

Here is an excerpt of the AS code:

```
    if (Adverts.isSupported)
    {
        var r:int = GoogleApiAvailability.instance.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable();
        if (r == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
        {
            Adverts.service.initialisePlatform(AdvertPlatform.PLATFORM_ADMOB, myAppId);
            if (Adverts.service.interstitials.isSupported)
            {
                // etc...
            }
            else trace("Interstitials not supported");
```

What am I doing wrong, or what could I do to find out what I am doing wrong?

(Could not add the `adverts` tag to this question because not enough reputation)

Answer (score 0):

Check what the value of your `myAppId` is.

That first error would indicate that it is `null` and the `initialisePlatform()` call is failing.